# Do while loop in Java types

Tags: java

Is following the valid do-while code?

```
do
   while (ii < table.length)
      System.out.println(ii++);
```

I have read and used only following do-while statement and came across above format recently!

```
    do{
      System.out.println(ii++);
    }while (ii < table.length)
```

Both the do-while are getting compiled but I am very surprised to see the first do-while type! What is its use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there more code to the first one? Seems like you cut it in half. Also, the second one is missing a `;`.

Comment: Does the following not answer your question: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html?

Comment: What is the result of the first do-while loop?

Comment: I doubt that the first example is compiling unless there's another `while (something);` immediately following your code.

Answer (score 2):

For your first example, try it out in your favorite IDE:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      ArrayList<Integer> foo = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
          foo.add(i);
      }

      int i = 0;

      do
          while (i < foo.size())
              System.out.println("foo[" + i + "]=" + i++);              
   }
}
```

You'll get a red squiggly (if using Eclipse) on the semi-colon at the end of:

```
System.out.println("foo[" + i + "]=" + i++);
```

Its an invalid construct per the Eclipse Java compiler (Sun's javac I can't say):

```
 Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete
```

Comment: Also should mention this pertains to Java 1.6 and 1.7 compliance settings, I also can't comment on Java 8.

Comment: Nothing was changed in Java 8 that would affect this.